# History of Green's function

Tags: reference-request

Could you give me some references about the history of the Green's function?
Thank you in advance for your reply
In the study of boundary value problems for differential and difference equations we transform our proplem to an equivalent integral equation and there where Green's function appears, how they get this idea of Green's functions? Where this function apears? In which cases,?

Comment: I think it would improve your question considerably if you present the function and your motivation around its history.

Comment: Please clarify. Are you asking what kind of work *motivated* George Green to come up with the class of functions we now call Green's functions? Most of his publications appear to be concerned with waves (water waves, sound waves, electromagnetic waves), specifically propagation, reflection, and refraction.

Comment: @njuffa Yes, please

Comment: @L_Green Please edit clarifications into the question text. I note that Google provides a [scan](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Mathematical_Papers_of_the_Late_George_G/FT3Q-q_wnxkC?hl=en&gbpv=1&pg=PR3&printsec=frontcover) of N. M. Ferrers (ed.), *Mathematical papers of the late George Green.* London: Macmillan 1871. Which of the papers collected there are the most relevant to the origin of Green's functions, I do not know, as mathematical physics is not my field.

Comment: J. Lutzen's "Prehistory of the theory of distributions" is wonderful...

Comment: Thank you so much !